# How to trigger ":target" CSS style with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

When you follow an anchor link like `<a href="#div">`, it will go to the element #div and display the CSS style for ":target", example: `#div:target { color: red }`.
I would like to know how to reproduce this functionality which occurs only when clicking an anchor link (hash).

The whole idea is that I want to custom handle an anchor link so it doesn't trigger the event (on)`popstate` each time it's clicked. It's very problematic for me that it triggers it.

So if I recode it manually with "scrollIntoView" or the equivalent in Jquery, add its entry to the history (which won't trigger "popstate") then the last thing to code is to trigger the ":target" pseudo-class style.

How to do so?

thank you

Comment: Why is that event problematic for you? If it's only the event that is the problem then be the first to register an handler for this event, using the capture mode and stopImmediatePropogation() the event object. You can keep the default behavior and not let any other script handle it.

Comment: @kaiido can you elaborate? i'm not really good with js at all

Comment: Simply answer my first question: "Why is that event problematic for you?"

Comment: Loading html with ajax creates problem with anchor links and when i try to solve the problem, it creates a problem with the history (button go back/forward of the browser). If I try to solve the history problem, initial bug rehappens. Normal links have been custom coded (prevent default behaviour), so I tried to do the same thing for anchor links. Prevent default behaviour disables the history event, but then I don't know how to trigger the :target effect :(.

Comment: So the popstate event isn't the problem, but the new history. Please edit your question.

Comment: any history action triggers "popstate", anyway i think it's unsolvable (or too advanced for me) and I have corrected the issue differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there's no way to use the `:target` psuedo-class and change the location without affecting the history,

So something like this should work for you. Basically setting `data-` attributes on the link pointing to where should be targeted and adding a class for the styling

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('a')].forEach(a => a.addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const targeted = document.querySelector(`[data-targetted="${a.dataset.target}"]`);

  if (!targeted) return;
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-targetted]')].forEach(elem => elem.classList.remove('target'))
  targeted.classList.add('target');
  targeted.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
}));
```

```css
div {
  height: 30vh;
}

div.target {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<a data-target="link1">Link 1</a>
<a data-target="link2">Link 2</a>
<a data-target="link3">Link 3</a>
<a data-target="link4">Link 4</a>
<a data-target="link5">Link 5</a>

<br/><br/>

<div data-targetted="link1">Link 1 Target</div>
<div data-targetted="link2">Link 2 Target</div>
<div data-targetted="link3">Link 3 Target</div>
<div data-targetted="link4">Link 4 Target</div>
<div data-targetted="link5">Link 5 Target</div>
```

Comment: I just tired and it triggers popstate `$(window).on('popstate', function(event) { console.log("ON POPSTATE") }` so it means it touches the history

Comment: Check out my edit, incase its what you're looking for :D

Comment: so instead of using href, using data-attribute... sure that would work but it's circonvoluted, and if there is no other way, then thank you!